# React from mapped components open dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, render

So my application is growing, and I am starting to wonder, what is the best approach in my case, to open dialog from mapped component.

So currently, I have events array of object, which i map and create new components.

EventFeed.js

```
events.map(event => <EventCard key={event._id} event={event}/>)
```

What i want to do from each eventcard on "More info" button click call dialog and pass event id to that dialog, my current aproach looks like this:

SingleEventCard

```
class RecipeReviewCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
      isgoing: this.props.isgoing,
      showModal1: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {  // switch the value of the showModal state
    this.setState({
      showModal1: !this.state.showModal1

    });
  }
  getComponent = () => {
    if (this.state.showModal1) {  // show the modal if state showModal is true
      return <EventView eventid={this.props.event._id} />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

render() {
return {

<Button onClick={this.handleClick}>More info</Button>
{this.getComponent()}
}
}
```

In render i have another views which I wont write(since no reason bunch of inputs and displays), the problem is that when I open dialog it messes up my event card style. Also I need to click two times next time in order to open. Can someone can offer more generic approach, where I can render  that dialog in other component or maybe something different?

Comment: What are the contents of the dialog? Input form? or just a message?

Comment: dialog will have more info about event, also , i want to make comment section